# Do I have to define every button on screen in xml if those buttons are generated in a grid every time a new game is made?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on a small personal project to port a version of the Same Game that I made to android. I have most of the game coded in java (still finishing it), but I am reading up on android development (reading the documentation and watching thenewboston on youtube). I am curious about the AndroidManifest.xml. If I understand correctly, everything that goes on screen is defined in that xml file. However, my java game has its own code to create the board:

```
 //game board
JFrame gameBoard = new JFrame();
gameBoard.setTitle("CrossGame");
gameBoard.setSize(400,400);

int numColors = 3;

//board grid
JPanel boardGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(gridSize, gridSize));

try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
//A loop to add a new button to each section of the board grid.
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {

    gameButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
    gameButtons[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener());
    gameButtons[i][j].setBackground(colors[(int)(Math.random() * numColors)]);
    boardGrid.add(gameButtons[i][j]);

  }
}

//Adds the grid of buttons to the window.
gameBoard.add(boardGrid);
//Quits the program when the close window button is pressed.
gameBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
gameBoard.setVisible(true);
```

}

I am programming on a Mac, which is why I have the setLookAndFeel in there. Do all these buttons have to be defined in the XML? Or do I have to revamp this code?

Comment: The `AndroidManifest` file is used to describe the components(Activities, Services, ContentProviders) and other settings(like permissions) for an app. Your entire app(or individual activities from the app) could have a custom theme set on them(in the AndroidManifest file) to explain how should the widgets look like. The widgets themselves will be created in code in the `Activity` or through a xml file(not the manifest) used as the content view for the `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Android do recommend to add button in xml to separate out Business and Presentation Layer. But it is not mandatory. So you can revamp them entirely in your code also just like java application

```
 For Example::
 for(int i::n)//depend upon your loop requirement
  {
      layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.statsviewlayout);
      Button bi = new Button(this);
      bi.setText(R.string.button_back);
      bi.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      layout.addView(bi);
  }
```

Comment: So the color of the buttons (which in this case is randomly generated from an array) would be defined in the R.string xml file? And could I modify the above loop to create a 2D array of buttons, or is that to be defined in the statsviewlayout? Finally, I don't see an actionListener there. Is that no longer needed, or is there a method that takes the place of actionListner?

Comment: You can definitely randomized button from array stored inside R.string.array xml file. You can also modify loop according to you requirement.

Comment: actionListener is like bi.setOnClickListener which you can also insert in the loop or outside the loop using it's b"i" according to event that need to be fired on clicking the button

Comment: And since that is XML, do I have to import a Color class like I do in Java, or does XML have colors readily accessible? Thanks, good to know about the setOnClickListener.

Comment: I'm afraid you've to create your own style xml just like css file. with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  <style name="Color">
        <item name="android:Color">#00FF00</item><item name="android:Color">#00FFF0</item></style></resources>

Comment: And in the xml statsviewlayout, that is where I would define the grid size of the game in xml? Just want to be clear.

Comment: yeah. Including GridView in statsviewlayout is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the interface dynamically as you do currently, however there are several advantages to using the XML layout facilities.

Firstly you need to be clear that there are many different xml files involved in an android application. The manifest file is not (in general ) oriented around screen layout.

If you were to use an xml layout file instead of dynamically creating your buttons, android provides excellent facilities for designing multiple versions for different device sizes and resolutions.

Comment: Could you recommend somewhere I could go to learn more about utilizing the XML? The only reason I wasn't really worried about it is because, for the scope of my project, I am only working with one device (Nexus 7).

Comment: I suggest you look at the android developers site intro projects - they show how to use view very explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomized the style using

#### array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<array name="color">
<item name="green">0000FF</item>
<item name="red">FF0000</item>
<item name="blue">00FF00</item>
</array>
```

#### You can use these array file in random fashion to style your button

```
  Resources re=getResources();
  bi.setBackGroundColor(random(r.getArray(color)));
```

Hope these might help your programming structure